# GORM Auto-increments primary key even if data wasnt inserted into DB

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

[image]

I have the following table `channels` in my db with `id` being primary key and `telegram_id` being unique.
If I try to run this code:

```
db.Create(&models.Channel{
        TelegramID: 5,
        Title:      "ok",
    })
```

it won't be inserted into db and the duplicate entry error will be logged in console.
However if I change `TelegramID` to be different (for example "6") and run the code, it will insert with ID being equal to 11, not to 10.
[image]

How can I make it not to auto-increment ID when the data is not inserted?

Comment: This is because on error the AUTO_INCREMENT values aren't rolled back, because if any other client has been inserted another id succesfully, you end up with duplicates on your next insert.

Comment: @Fenistil got it, thank you! Now I understand I don't have to worry about it.